# How to filtering in Typo3 with categories and subcategories

Tags: mysql, typo3, typoscript

I have several pages in Typo3 with products, to each of which different product groups and properties can be assigned - for this I use the Typo3 categories. There are 5 main categories, each with several subcategories:

```
Series  [id=1]   |  Shape   [id=2] |  Color   [id=3] |  Decor   [id=4] |  Widths  [id=5] 
-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|----------------
Series #1 [id=8] | Shape #1 [id=10]| Color #1 [id=15]| Decor #1 [id=18]| Width #1 [id=23] 
Series #2 [id=6] | Shape #2 [id=9] | Color #2 [id=17]| Decor #2 [id=19]| Width #2 [id=22] 
Series #3 [id=27]| Shape #3 [id=11]| Color #3 [id=16]| Decor #3 [id=20]| Width #3 [id=24] 
                 | Shape #4 [id=13]|                 | Decor #4 [id=21]| Width #4 [id=25] 
                 | Shape #5 [id=12]|                 |                 | Width #5 [id=26]
```

Based on these categories, the output of product teasers is to be filtered. You should be able to choose one or more product series and further narrow down the selection by choosing the other categories.

In my opinion, the sub-categories have to be linked with OR, while the main categories have to be linked with AND.

But how do I do that?

I have tried this with the following typoscript, unfortunately without success:

```
lib.product-teaser = COA
lib.product-teaser {

    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = pages
        select {
            pidInList.data = register:dTid
            recursive = 5

            selectFields.dataWrap = *, sys_category.uid AS catUid, pages.uid AS pgUid, pages.title AS pgTitle, tt_content.uid AS recUid
            join = sys_category_record_mm ON pages.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local JOIN tt_content ON pages.uid = tt_content.pid
            groupBy = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign

            where {

                cObject = COA
                cObject {

                    10 = TEXT
                    10 {
                        value = tt_content.CType='mask_cnt_tsr_page'
                    }

                    20 = TEXT
                    20 {
                        if.isGreaterThan.data = register:dCid1
                        if.value = 0
                        value.dataWrap = AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ({register:dCid1})
                        #dCid1 contain a comma-seperated list of IDs of the subcategories from the specific main categorie (id=1), which the user has selected.
                    }

                    30 = TEXT
                    30 {
                        if.isGreaterThan.data = register:dCid2
                        if.value = 0
                        value.dataWrap = AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ({register:dCid2})
                        # dCid2 contain a comma-seperated list of IDs of the subcategories from the specific main categorie (id=2), which the user has selected.
                    }

                    40 = TEXT
                    40 {
                        if.isGreaterThan.data = register:dCid3
                        if.value = 0
                        value.dataWrap = AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ({register:dCid3})
                        # dCid3 contain a comma-seperated list of IDs of the subcategories from the specific main categorie (id=3), which the user has selected.
                    }

                    50 = TEXT
                    50 {
                        if.isGreaterThan.data = register:dCid4
                        if.value = 0
                        value.dataWrap = AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ({register:dCid4})
                        # dCid4 contain a comma-seperated list of IDs of the subcategories from the specific main categorie (id=4), which the user has selected.
                    }

                    60 = TEXT
                    60 {
                        if.isGreaterThan.data = register:dCid5
                        if.value = 0
                        value.dataWrap = AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_local IN ({register:dCid5})
                        # dCid5 contain a comma-seperated list of IDs of the subcategories from the specific main categorie (id=5), which the user has selected.
                    }



                }

            }


        }

        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            [...]
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TypoScript I would go with a userFunc and do that in PHP because you have beter control, possible debug options and far less boilerplate. It might be possible to do that in plain TS but there is no point in doing it if you can do it with PHP when this is faster and better.

```
uidInList.stdWrap.cObject = USER
uidInList.stdWrap.cObject.userFunc = Vendor\YourSitePackage\Collection.php
```

The docs can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't know if I can solve the problem with a PHP userFunc - in my opinion, it's more likely due to the MySQL-WHERE query, which (apparently) doesn't work like that, right? Do you perhaps know a solution?